# C# getting error calling Rest Api: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, json, rest, proxy

I'm trying to call a vendor rest API but no luck. Using the same Endpoint URL, Authorization (username:password), and proxy, I can get to it using System.Net.WebClient. That gives me a clue that my endpoint url, username, password and proxy are correct. But the preferred way to use System.Net.Http. Please advise what am I doing wrong.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;

namespace RestApi
{
    public class APIFetch
    {
        const string getUsersEndpoint = @"https://client.vendor.com/client/users?filterid=long-id";
        const string authorizationHeaderValue = "username:password"; //for restful service
        public static void GetAllUsers()
        {
           
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUsersEndpoint);
            request.Headers.Add authorizationHeaderValue);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
  

            WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("http://ourProxy:8088");
            myProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
           
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Proxy = myProxy;

            try
            {
                //Get exception on next line
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();

//save to object code
                }
                //return response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                //Getting this message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.


                
            }

        }
    }
}
```